# append a Name Value pair to other one

Tags: java, namevaluecollection

here is the code of the calling method -

```
NameValuePair[] data = {
        new NameValuePair("first_name", firstName),
        new NameValuePair("last_name", lastName),
        new NameValuePair("email", email),
        new NameValuePair("company", organization),
        new NameValuePair("phone", phone)
    };
    SalesForceFormSubmissionUtil.submitForm(data,CONTACT_FOR_TYPE);
```

In the called method -

```
  public static void submitForm(NameValuePair[] givendata, String contactType) {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(Constants.SALESFORCE_URL);
    NameValuePair[] data = {
        new NameValuePair("oid", Constants.SALESFORCE_OID),
        new NameValuePair(Constants.SALESFORCE_CAMPAIGN_ID, contactType)
    };
    post.setRequestBody(data);
```

i want to add both the givendata & data and send it as a post request. Can you guys suggest me how to append both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to combine the two arrays you can create a third array (`combinedData`) with a size of `givenData.length` + `data.length`, then you'll have to copy the elements from your source arrays.

Though, there are plenty of other methods to solve this, as an example; below is an implementation using a `ArrayList` as a middle-man/helper.

```
String[] A1 = {"hello","world"};
String[] A2 = {"I","am","bored"};

...

ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String> (A1.length + A2.length);

temp.addAll (Arrays.asList (A1));
temp.addAll (Arrays.asList (A2));

String[] A3 = temp.toArray (new String[temp.size ()]);

...

for (int i=0; i < A3.length; ++i)
  System.out.println (A3[i]);
```

output

```
hello
world
I
am
bored
```

Comment: Thanx for you solution refp..  one small doubt - Can we declare a dyanamic array( temp array), without mentioning a specific size.

Comment: No, Arrays are fixed in size. If you want a dynamic container that is very similar to Array use an [ArrayList<T>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). You don't have to specify the length of `temp` in my snippet above, I just did that to show the "proper" (most optimized) way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void submitForm(NameValuePair[] givendata, String contactType) {
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   PostMethod post = new PostMethod(Constants.SALESFORCE_URL);
   post.setRequestBody(givendata);
   post.addParameters({
      new NameValuePair("oid", Constants.SALESFORCE_OID),
      new NameValuePair(Constants.SALESFORCE_CAMPAIGN_ID, contactType)
   });
   ...
```